# Where to validate AutoMapper Configuration in ASP.Net Core application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Building an ASP.Net Core 2.0 web application and can't figure out where to validate the AutoMapper configuration.

In my `ConfigureServices()` method, I have

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

And I'm registering my mappings in an Automapper Profile

```
public class MyAutomapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MyAutomapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<FooDto, FooModel>();
        CreateMap<BarDto, BarModel>();
    }
}
```

But it's not clear where to call

```
Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: The best place to call AssertConfigurationIsValid is in a unit test. See also http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu that works fine IFF you have unit tests in your application *and* you can guarantee that the configuration used in your unit tests is *exactly* the same as used in in the "real" application.

Comment: I'm not going to comment on having unit tests :) But there is no reason why the configuration couldn't be the same in unit tests. You should make sure it is. That's what makes the tests useful.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After digging around in the `IMapper` interface (and thanks to the [documentation link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection#configuration-validation) provided by @LucianBargaoanu), I found exactly what I needed.

In `ConfigureServices()`:

```
        // Adds AutoMapper to DI configuration and automagically scans the 
        // current assembly for any classes that inherit Profile 
        // and registers their configuration in AutoMapper
        services.AddAutoMapper();
```

The secret sauce is to add `IMapper mapper` as a parameter to `Configure()` - the parameter list is dependency-injected so you can reference any service registered in `ConfigureServices()`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ... , IMapper mapper)
{
  ...
        mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Works exactly as expected.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks - I swear I searched long and hard and didn't run across that documentation. I'll amend my answer to reflect the "better" way to do the validation.

Comment: If someone looked for it and did not find it in the docs, it appears it was removed with no explanation recently. The solution still work though. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/commit/cfd27e2862fa0bfc5d737a261e9a124a141aa5fa#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8

Comment: This seems like a bad idea - Configure is called by the runtime to configure the HTTP pipeline. You could wrap the assertConfigurationIsValid call with if (env.IsDevelopment()), but this still feels like the wrong way to go about it. A unit test feels like a better fit.

Answer (score 18):

The [recommended approach](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/commit/cfd27e2862fa0bfc5d737a261e9a124a141aa5fa#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8) (see JBogard's response) is to move this test into a unit test:

```
public class MappingTests
{
    private readonly IMapper _sut;

    public MappingTests() => _sut = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<MyAutomapperProfile>(); }).CreateMapper();

    [Fact]
    public void All_mappings_should_be_setup_correctly() => _sut.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```